# Laravel artisan tinker - "quiet mode" - don't print query results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

How can I store the results of an Eloquent query to a variable in tinker, without printing the results to the console?

For example, when I run `$threads = App\Thread::all()` I want to only store the results in the variable `$threads` without seeing all the threads. Is there something like 'quiet mode' in tinker?

Comment: You can't do that without modifying Tinker.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tinker dumps the output of the last command executed. So a hackish trick to suppress any output is to append a null statement:

```
>>> $threads = App\Thread::all(); '';
```

Comment: Too bad there's no option. It's pretty time consuming